# The GLSL Doesn't Work

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, game-engine, shaders

There was a question about someone not being able to use GLSL shading and there was an answer which almost worked but half of the game was all black with a huge shadow. Please tell me a way to fix this.

This is how it looks when it's not rendered:

[image]

This is how it looks when it is rendered:

[image]

This is how the lamp settings look like:

[image]

This is how the shading settings look like:

[image]

If you find a way to fix this then please tell me because it's really annoying.

This sometimes fixes itself when I save the game and open the blend file again but not always.

Comment: Have you tried to mix Hemi lamps with Sun lamps? It doesn't seem a GLSL problem to me...

Comment: could share you .blend please? it would help a lot with investigating the problem.

Comment: It's not a problem anymore it only happens when I change the tool to rotation.

Comment: if it happens sometimes, or happens all the time, it's still a problem, it's 90% that your mix file is damaged for some reason, since it's not a problem of lights, I've also used sun lights and hemi and not cause no problem while maintaining the proper balance between one and the other upload your blend to be reviewed [Upload Blender exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)